# Adding extra dimension to multidimensional numpy images in Python3

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, image, numpy

Suppose I have an image of dimension (160, 1, 256, 192), i.e., 160 gray scale images of dimension 256x192 of single channel. How will I make the image of dimension (160,3,256,192) by just copying the 256x192 images in the three channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`np.repeat(x, 3, axis=1)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html).